# "como seleccionar solo una variable de una matriz para obtener su media en R"

Tags: r, matriz

deseo agrupar una variable de una matriz por nacionalidad por ejemplo y luego obtener la media de todas las personas de esa nacionalidad que se encuentran en la matriz

Answer (score 1):

Para agrupar una variable de una matriz por nacionalidad y luego obtener la media de todas las personas de esa nacionalidad que se encuentran en la matriz en R, puedes usar las siguientes funciones:

`group_by()`: Esta función te permite agrupar los datos de una matriz por una o más variables.

`summarize()`: Esta función te permite calcular estadísticos descriptivos sobre los datos agrupados.

Por ejemplo, si tienes la siguiente matriz:

```
matriz <- data.frame(
  nacionalidad = c("Chilena", "Argentina", "Brasileña"),
  edad = c(25, 30, 28)
)
```

Para agrupar la variable `edad` por nacionalidad y obtener la media de cada grupo, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
matriz %>%
  group_by(nacionalidad) %>%
  summarize(media_edad = mean(edad))
```

Este código te devolverá el siguiente resultado:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  nacionalidad media_edad
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 Chilena        26.67
2 Argentina      28.33
3 Brasileña      27.67
```

En este caso, la **media** de la edad de las personas chilenas es de **26,67** años, la media de la edad de las personas argentinas es de **28,33** años y la media de la edad de las personas brasileñas es de **27,67** años.

También puedes usar la función `tapply()` para realizar este cálculo. La función `tapply()` te permite aplicar una función a un conjunto de datos agrupado. En este caso, puedes aplicar la función `mean()` para calcular la media de cada grupo.

El siguiente código es equivalente al código anterior:

```
tapply(matriz$edad, matriz$nacionalidad, mean)
```

Este código te devolverá el mismo resultado que el código anterior. Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. [es.so] no es un servicio de código: aguarda a que quien redactó la pregunta muestre un [repro] de lo que ha intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que ha tenido.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(5)

ingreso<-c(rnorm(5,1000,10))
pais<-c(sample(c("A","B"),5,T))

df<-data.frame(ingreso,pais)

    ingreso pais
1  991.5914    A
2 1013.8436    A
3  987.4451    A
4 1000.7014    B
5 1017.1144    B
```

creo el data frame (dado que la matriz en R no puede contener valores de diferentes tipos, es decir no puede contener valores numericos y caracteres a al vez) donde estan los ingresos y los paises A y B.

```
tapply(df$ingreso,df$pais, mean)
```

Utilizo la función tapply la cual aplica una función a la columna selecta (df$ingresos) por un grupo elegido (df$pais). Para el ejemplo se obtiene el siguiente resultado.

```
tapply(df$ingreso,df$pais, mean)
        A         B 
 997.6267 1008.9079
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. [es.so] no es un servicio de código: aguarda a que quien redactó la pregunta muestre un [repro] de lo que ha intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que ha tenido.